# Swift3 Use of unresolved identifier 'Date'

Tags: swift3

I am trying to get Date in Swift3 using

```
let date = Date()
```

but it is showing "error: use of unresolved identifier 'Date'" How to resolve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It resolved. need to `import Foundation`

Answer (score 3):

import foundation  doesn't work
but
import Foundation work perfectly

modules are case sensitive .